# Extracting XElement children and grandchildren by name

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I have an XElement (myParent) containing multiple levels of children that I wish to extract data from.  The elements of interest are at known locations in the parent.

I understand that I am able to get a child element by:

```
myParent.Element(childName);
```

or

```
myParent.Element(level1).Element(childName);
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this if I want to loop through an array offor a list of elements that are at different levels, and looping through the list.  For instance, I am interested in getting the following set of elements:

```
myParent.Element("FieldOutputs").Element("Capacity");
myParent.Element("EngOutputs").Element("Performance")
myParent.Element("EngOutputs").Element("Unit").Element("Efficiency")
```

How can I define these locations in an array so that I can simply loop through the array?

i.e.

```
string[] myStringArray = {"FieldOutputs.Capacity", "EngOutputs.Performance", "EngOutputs.Unit.Efficiency"};

for (int i=0; i< myArray.Count(); i++)
{
    XElement myElement = myParent.Element(myStringArray);
}
```

I understand that the method above does not work, but just wanted to show effectively what I am trying to achieve.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thank you,
Justin

Comment: I think that all you may need is Descendants, but I'm still unclear about what kind of result you want. Maybe mock small input & output samples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While normally I'm reluctant to suggest using XPath, it's probably the most appropriate approach here, using [`XPathSelectElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156083.aspx):

```
string[] paths = { "FieldOutputs/Capacity", "EngOutputs/Performance", 
                   "EngOutputs/Unit/Efficiency"};

foreach (string path in paths)
{
    XElement element = parent.XPathSelectElement(path);
    if (element != null)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it :).  Out of curiosity, why are you generally reluctant to suggest XPath?  Maybe it's just because I have a heavy XSLT background, but I find it to be a succinct way of selecting elements.

Comment: @James: Within C#, I think of it as "code within data" - making it harder to work with than "real code" calls to methods etc. Also, it's much easier to work with namespaces in LINQ to XML when you're using code than using XPath. XPath is fine in its place, but when I can use the direct methods in LINQ to XML instead, I tend to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Descendants()` method is what you're looking for, I believe.  For example:

```
var descendants = myParent.Descendants();
foreach (var e in descendants) {
  ...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants.aspx

**Edit:**

Looking at your question more closely, it looks like you may want to use XPathSelectElements()

```
var descendants = myParent.XPathSelectElements("./FieldOutputs/Capacity | ./EngOutputs/Performance | ./EngOutputs/Units/Efficency");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx